# Swift 3 Overload Operators for Protocols

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, operator-overloading

I have a **protocol** that declares property of type `Int`. I also have few classes that conforms that `Protocol`, and now I need to overload operator `+` for all of them. Since operator `+` will work based on the property declared, I don't want to implement that operator in each class separately.

So I have

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var property: Int { get }
}
```

And I would want to have something like

```
extension MyProtocol {
    static func +(left: MyProtocol, right: MyProtocol) -> MyProtocol {
        // create and apply operations and return result
    }
}
```

And actually I successfully did that, but trying to work with it I get an error `ambiguous reference to member '+'`.

When I move operator overload func to the each class separately, issue disappeared, but I'm still looking for a solution to make it works with Protocols.

Answer (score 5):

Solved, by moving `func +...` outside of Extension, so it is just a method in the file where `MyProtocol` is declared

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var property: Int { get }
}

func +(left: MyProtocol, right: MyProtocol) -> MyProtocol {
    // create and apply operations and return result
}
```